# Html to Pdf converted pdf has "#" for some characters

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox, html-to-pdf, openhtmltopdf

I'm converting HTML to PDF with openhtmltopdf library, but the converted PDF uses "#" instead of characters like "İ","ş","Ş","ç","Ç","Ö". How can I solve it?

**Java code:**

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream renderedPdfBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
builder.withHtmlContent(htmlContent, "/");
builder.toStream(renderedPdfBytes);
builder.run();
renderedPdfBytes.close();
byte[] renderedPdf = renderedPdfBytes.toByteArray(); 

try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile)) {
    fos.write(renderedPdf);
}
```

**Html content:**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="close-icon close"></span>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"><h2>İade Prosedürü 27.09.2023</h2></div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="margin-bottom: 50px;"><p>İade edilmek istenen.</p></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**HTML View:**

[image]

**Converted PDF View:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing issues with characters not being displayed correctly in the PDF generated using the openhtmltopdf library, it may be related to font embedding or font support.
You can modify the code to include custom fonts with proper character support. Here is the example of it.

```
PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
// Use Noto Sans font (or any other font with proper character support)
builder.useFont(() -> {
    try (InputStream inputStream = HtmlToPdfConverter.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/NotoSans-Regular.ttf")) {
        return FontUtil.createFont(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer would be vastly better if you show **how** to do this, and which font the OP should use.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, the answer is updated. Hope that works.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I tried this code block but I couldn't find FontUtil class and used useFont method but it didn't effect. Have you any advice for solution? 

Code:
            `URL url = Main.class.getResource("/Poppins-Regular.ttf");`
            `builder.useFont(new File(url.toURI()), "Poppins", null, null, false);`
Log:
`com.openhtmltopdf.load INFO:: TIME: parse stylesheets 34ms`
`com.openhtmltopdf.match INFO:: media = print`
`com.openhtmltopdf.match INFO:: Matcher created with 160 selectors`
`com.openhtmltopdf.load INFO:: Loading font(Poppins) from PDFont supplier now.`